# How to make a site-scraping queue with for() for CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I wonder why I can't get this CasperJS code to work. My main goal is to save some pages, the pages html contains two dynamic values put into url. The problem is that CasperJS seems to run it's code after the for() code is done and only the last page is saved. How can I make this to work?

```js
var site_list = new Array('stoarge1','storage2','storage3');
var input_list = new Array('','y1','y2','y3');


var random_url = 'https://page.com';

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start(random_url, function() {
});


//
var time = 3000;

for (var i=0; i<site_list.length; i++) {
 for (var j=0; j<input_list.length; j++) {

  var site = site_list[i];
  var input = input_list[j];

  var url = 'https://page.com/' + site + '?=p'+ input;
  var save = '/mydrive/' + site + '_' + input +'.html';

  casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
   this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());

   var fs = require('fs');
   var html = this.getPageContent();
   var f = fs.open(save, 'w');
   f.write(html);
   f.close();

   this.echo(site + ' - ' + input + ' (' + j + '/' + input_list.length +')');

  });


 }
}

casper.run(function () {
 this.echo('Done').exit();
});
```

Comment: You open the file for writing (which automatically overwrites any previous data in the file) with `fs.open(save, 'w')`. Change that line to `fs.open(save, 'a')`, which will append new data to it rather than overwrite it (notice I changed the `w` to and `a`). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed. Still returns only the last one. When I output this.echo(site + ' - ' + input + ' (' + j + '/' + input_list.length +')') it acts as if it's the last i and j.

Comment: So it saves all text as the last text, overwriting each other instead of creating 12 unique ones.

Comment: Are you saying that they overwrite "each other instead of creating 12 unique ones" when you change it to append (`a`), or write (`w`)"?

Comment: Yes, I think it's because a unique url is put into each casper.thenOpen(url, function() { but the last i value (3) and j value (4) is put into the function creating so that the save variable becomes the same for every unique url.